# Does type hinting class members shadow previously defined or built-in variables?

Tags: python, python-typing, shadowing

With type-hinting, defining a class in Python goes from

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = 5
```

to something like this

```
class SomeClass:
    id: int

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.id = 5
```

However, a linter like `ruff` has an issue with the `id: int` line, which apparently would shadow the built-in `id`. That feels like a suprising behaviour to me, since in previous, type-hint-less times, `id` would have always been used as `self.id` with no shadowing whatsoever.

So I would like to know: is there really shadowing occurring and if so, to which extent, i.e. what is the scope of this shadowing?

Comment: It's telling you you cannot use the builtin `id()` in the rest of the `class` definition block. Which is probably fairly inconsequential…

Comment: "With type-hinting, defining a class in Python goes from ... to ..." Could you elaborate on why the explicit declaration of an attribute is necessary?

Comment: @PawełRubin consider it a choice -- you basically define a contract, what you think your code is supposed to be doing. The typechecker can tell you if you are wrong. In this particular instance, `mypy` needs as many type hints as possible to do the best possible job, so it becomes a  habit.

Comment: You don't have to add a type annotation in this case. **mypy** and other type checkers will infer the type of the `id` attribute to be an `int`.

If however, you'd like to define a _contract_, you can inline the type annotation: `self.id: int = 5`.

Comment: @PawełRubin certainly. However, the example in this question is explicitely simplified. In the real world, I'm dealing with Pydantic models, which do require explicit typing.

Comment: Got it. I think it's worth mentioning in the original question as it is not obvious.

Comment: Not quite sure about that, since SO usually asks to provide a minimal example for the problem and since it only manifests with type hints, I had to provide those. But either way, I think your answer is the one I've been looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The builtin `id` will be shadowed in the scope of the class definition block. Consider the following example:

```py
class SomeClass:
    id = lambda _: "overriden!"
    print(id(42))  # prints 'overriden'

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        print(id(42))


SomeClass()  # prints an address
print(id(42))  # prints an address
```